# bus error caused by print statement

Tags: c++

Ok so I have simple function that returns the highest non-pair card from a 5 card poker hand.  But he problem I'm having is wierd.  There is this random bus error that occurs randomly, and I don't know for what reason. I thought it was the print statements I was using but now I'm not sure.  I know it looks a mess, but if you look at the line below where I print the words "test print", can someone tell me why immediately after this line theres a bus error and it doesn't get to the second "test print" statement.  Could I have run out of memory for my program???  That probably makes no sense, but I can't really think of anything else (please exclude the slightly confusing code):

```
int Hand::highestNonPair(int *face_array_exclude, int size)
{
    int highest = 0;
    int contains_excludable = 0;
    int i = 0;

    if(this->hasAnother(i) == false)
            highest = cards[i]->getFace();


    for(i= 0;i<cards.size();i++)
    {
        if((cards[i+1]->getFace() > cards[i]->getFace()) &&
        (this->hasAnother(i) == false)){
            if(size>0){
                for(int c = 0;c<size;c++){
                    if(cards[i]->getFace() == face_array_exclude[c])
                            contains_excludable = 1;
                    }
             }

                 if(!contains_excludable)
            highest = cards[i+1]->getFace();

        cout<<\nTEST PRINT"<<endl;
        contains_excludable = 0;
        cout<<\nTEST PRINT"<<endl;
        }
    }

    return highest;
}
```

Comment: to start off, your cout statements are missing a quotation mark.

Comment: The rows containing cards[i+1]->getFace() looks a bit suspect since you are iterating from 0 to < cards.size(). For the last index it seems like this is outside of the cards array. Using a debugger could be helpful.

Comment: One potential problem is using `cards[i+1]` when `i` is at its maximum value.

Comment: what does the debugger say? Run it under a debugger (u dont way what toolchian u r using so i cant be more specific) and it will tell you which line made it go bang

Comment: What _is_ a "bus error"?

Comment: @Chad On some platforms, bus error happens when dereferencing a pointer with nonzero LSBs, like `*(int*)0xdeadf00d`

Comment: Unrelated note:  that `if (size > 0)` around your inner loop is redundant.  As written, the inner loop won't run if `size <= 0`.  No need for the `if` statement.

Comment: @void - Why not post your own answer?

Comment: @EdHeal: I thought about that, but my answer would only differ slightly from your answer by the loop conditions, e.g. `for (i = 1; i < cards.size(); ++i)`.  That didn't feel different enough to warrant my own answer.  Hopefully, I didn't come off as picking on you in my comments, either.  :)

Answer (score 3):

The bit can case problems:

```
if((cards[i+1]->getFace() > cards[i]->getFace()) &&
```

As the highest value of `i` could be `cards.size() - 1`. This would mean that `cards[i+1` will be an invalid entry.

Change the loop:

```
for(i= 0;i<cards.size();i++)
```

to

```
for(i= 0;i<cards.size() - 1;i++)
```

Perhaps

Comment: What if `cards.size()` is zero?  Perhaps `for (i = 1; i < cards.size(); i++)` instead?

Comment: The `i<cards.size() - 1` -> `0 < -1` Which is false so it does not do the loop at all.

Comment: `cards.size()` is typically an unsigned integer (at least for STL containers).  In that case, if `cards.size()` is zero subtracting one from it will result in the largest value of the unsigned size type.  That means the loop **will** run if `size()` is zero since `0 < 0xFFFFFFFFu`, assuming the size type is a 32 bit unsigned integer.